# Trying to use grid view with my data, but it outputs an error

Tags: vb.net

Following is the code am using to bind the grid, can anyone please suggest me what am doing wrong in this snippet

```
    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SHAHRUKH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vb;User ID=sa;Password=sa@1234"
    con.Open()
    sql = "Data Source=SHAHRUKH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vb;User ID=****;Password=*****"
    cmd.CommandText = "select * From demo_vb  Where ID = '" & txtbox4.Text & "'"
    adapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.ItemsSource = New DataView()
    GridView1.DisplayMemberPath = "ID"
    con.Close()
```

I get this error:

> The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'

Comment: Can you post the error details?

Comment: ya error invalid exception handling "  The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'." this is error

Comment: You are missing this one :  adapter.SelectCommand = cmd. So add this one before adapter.Fill(ds).

Comment: after adding  adapter.SelectCommand = cmd now that error in  not solved still the another error Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.is come now

Comment: hi rakib    , after adding that the new error is comes that error is " Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized." pls give me solution about that

Comment: You have to pass the con to the SqlCoammd ike this: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", con);

Comment: still the error is come

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUNTECH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=iSense;Integrated Security=True;");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Picture from Images",con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;

    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help

```
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SHAHRUKH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vb;User ID=sa;Password=sa@1234")
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sql As New SqlCommand("select * From demo_vb  Where ID = '" & txtbox4.Text & "'",con)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql)
        con.Open()
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.datasource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.databind()
        con.Close()
```